# Process infinite input from external command line by line

Tags: java, scala, java-io

I have a program that reads in output from an external command and process line by line. However, when the external command outputs infinitely (prints some string in an infinite loop for instance), the program seems to be blocked and delayed - it buffers output and prints everything altogether when terminated. What's the best way to process infinite data input from another process, so that the program can process data "same time" as the external one is writing? Is there any high level API that works with this case, where I don't need to use monitor or other concurrency stuff? Thanks! I code in Scala, so both Scala and Java library would help. Here's Scala code segment.

```
val pb = new ProcessBuilder("./streamTest.py")
val p = pb.start()
val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))
var line = reader.readLine()
while(line != null) {
  println(line)
  line = reader.readLine()
}
reader.close()
```

Same code segment in Java:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./streamTest.py");
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = reader.readLine();
while(line != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
  line = reader.readLine();
}
reader.close();
```

Here's an example of external script streamTest.py that doesn't work. If I change the command to simpler ones that terminate such as "ls -l", that is, let pb be new ProcessBuilder("ls -l"), the program works fine.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import time
while True: 
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Hello World!")
```

Comment: the string that it prints on a loop, is it a line from the text file, a blank space or something else?

Comment: Where are you printing a *line*?

Comment: @Nagarz, Oh there's no text file. In the Java/Scala program, in each iteration of while loop, it prints a line read in from Process p's standard output. p.getInputStream() passes the process's stdout to stream reader in Java.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, At line 6 of the Java/Scala program, it prints the line read in. Actually "print" is just an example way of processing each line of data the program read in - in an actual application, "print" is replaced by some real processing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Python not to buffer the output.

Following solutions are possible.

**manual flush**

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import time
import sys
while True: 
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Hello World!")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

**change buffering mode of stdout**

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import time
import sys
import os
sys.stdout = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0)
while True: 
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Hello World!")
```

**execute the script in unbuffered mode**

```
#! /usr/bin/python -u
import time
while True: 
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Hello World!")
```

or

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "-u", "./streamTest.py");
```

or

```
# set an environment variable before calling the Java application
export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x
```

Other solutions possible.

Comment: Thank you so much! The python script is just an example. What if the process is a bash script or some other unix command utility that infinitely outputs something? Thanks!

Comment: @user3427270 It depends on the other process buffering mode. So you have to change it for the other process. Java can only read what the other process send to stdout. The buffering mainly occures when a subprocess has no terminal assigned. Because "no terminal" means "no user can see it" following "no need for immediate output". If you want to have a different behavior you have to change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print()
```

method does not flush.Therefore you cannot read it from the other java process.You may add this line after print method :

```
 System.out.flush();
```

Or you may just write

```
System.out.println("hello world");
```

since println() method automatically flushes as stated in [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)

> a PrintStream can be created so as to flush automatically; this means that the flush method is automatically invoked after a byte array is written, one of the println methods is invoked, or a newline character or byte ('\n') is written.

Comment: Well I missed the point that you print "hello world" in scala, not in java. Anyway same solution is given for scala by @SubOptimal

Comment: `Hello World!` is printed in a Python script. user3427270 want to read this output either in a Scala or java application. ;-)

Comment: ohh, yeah you are right  :) so my answer also counts , thanks:) @SubOptimal